# Check whether the application has read access to a folder (FindFirstFile returns "Access denied" but _access succeeds)

Tags: windows, winapi, permissions, directory-permissions

I'm enumerating contents of a folder with `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`. The problem I'm facing is that some of the sub-folders found cannot be enumerated in turn, `FindFirstFile` returns "Access is denied." So I want to check for this condition and not include such-subfolders into the list in the first place. I've found two possible solutions: check the path with `_access()`, or check the actual permissions in detail with `AccessCheck`, but the latter is said to be heavy-weight, unlike `_access()`, because you need to open and close a handle. Problem is, `_access` always succeeds for all the folders that I can't enumerate with `FindFirstFile`. Is there any other solution besides `AccessCheck`?

Another head-on approach would be to call `FindFirstFile` right away, but that, again, seems a waste (and I would also first need to determine whether the item is a folder, so even more extra work).

Comment: Call FindFirstFile, and if it fails deal with the error. It's really that simple.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As I mentioned, that solution is on the table but it seems quite crude, and needs extra work determining if an item is even a file. Hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: No extra work. If the function fails, then you can't enumerate its children. Also, identifying directories is simple.

Comment: the `_waccess` internal call `GetFileAttributes` and return value based on file attributes (are say read-only, etc). nothing common with security. simply call `FindFirstFile`  and if you have no `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` access it return error to you. are file is folder - check `dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` from `WIN32_FIND_DATA`. if you worry about efficient - at first stop use `FindFirstFile` at all. how minimum `FindFirstFileEx` with `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` or the best `NtQueryDirectoryFile`

Comment: @RbMm: Interesting, I was not aware `FindFirstFileEx` and `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, thank you.

Comment: @RbMm: `FindFirstFileEx` with `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` is not dramatically faster, but it is faster. Have not tried `NtQueryDirectoryFile` yet.

Comment: if correct use `NtQueryDirectoryFile` with big enough buffer it will be more faster compare `FindFirstFileEx+FindNextFile` because `FindFirstFileEx` how minimum 2 times call `NtQueryDirectoryFile` when possible do single call. also `NtQueryDirectoryFile` allow asynchronous request

Comment: Note that recent versions of `FindFirstFileEx` use the newer syscall `NtQueryDirectoryFileEx`. This has a new `QueryFlags` parameter that supports the new flag `SL_RETURN_ON_DISK_ENTRIES_ONLY`, which corresponds to `FIND_FIRST_EX_ON_DISK_ENTRIES_ONLY`. Probably you'll never need this flag, but going forward `QueryFlags` may be extended to support new semantics.

Answer (score 2):

The comments on my question are helpful and provide the easiest solution to the problem as formulated, but during further research I've found that the folders I cannot enumerate are links, they have the attribute bit `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` set in their `WIN32_FIND_DATA::dwAttributes` field. Checking for that was enough for me to implement special handling for these items.

Comment: this not correct - reparse  point can be enumerated also. another question - are this is need

Comment: @RbMm: `FindFirstFile` fails with `Access denied" if the path ends with a reparse point, e. g. "C:\Users\Username\Application Data". I assume the reparse point must be resolved first before enumerating is possible, and resolving them seems quite complicated and very heavy, e. g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21202/Reparse-Points-in-Vista
And it seems I'm not the first one to encounter this very problem: https://github.com/dagolden/Path-Tiny/issues/160

Comment: @PaulSanders: I'm not sure what exactly it is that you'd like to see, the code I "invented" is literally one `if` statement checking `dwAttributes` as I iterate over directory contents with `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I was interested as to why you and RnMm have differing views as to the semantics of FindFirstFile / FindNextFile when applied to a reparse point, that's all.  But I see from your comment above that you have answered that so I'm happy now.

Comment: Being denied access in this case has nothing to do with the directory being a reparse point. Junctions such as "%UserProfile%\Application Data" are there for compatibility. You can traverse them, but their discretionary security has an entry that denies read/list access.

Comment: you get access denied for concrete file. but not because it reparse point. for example if you have enabled backup privilege for thread - you can open it

Comment: @PaulSanders - `FindFirstFile` open reparse point target (not use `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` attribute when open file). we can enumerate reparse points links too, if we have access to it, and it target is correct

Comment: @RbMm  Well, you can't _both_ be right! (Unless I'm missing something)  That;s why I wanted to see the code.

Comment: @PaulSanders - if you look *Application Data* dacl (permissions) you can view that at first place here access **denied** ace for everyone which disable file read data(list directory) access. because this `FindFirstFile` fail. not because it repase point. this here is unrelated

Comment: we can not enumerate folders if we have not `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` (1) access to it. simply because we fail open it. are folder is reparse point or not - unrelated here

Comment: @RbMm Makes sense.

Comment: @RbMm: Hm, thank you for the explanation. Then my solution is not actually a solution and I have to re-write the code again.

Comment: What's to rewrite in any significant way? If you aren't granted access to list the directory, just skip it. These compatibility junctions are implemented this way on purpose to prevent descending into them automatically when listing the parent directory recursively. Not being able to list "Application Data" is no loss; you'll pick it up at "AppData\Roaming".

Comment: @eryksun: yes, of course. I was only referring to the way how I detect untraversable directories. Although I don't get the point of this junction's existence if it's not transparent to applications. Seems just extra unneeded clutter in the file system.

Comment: These junctions provide compatibility with applications that hard code the old paths, such as `"%UserProfile%\Application Data\Microsoft"`. This path works fine.